# .Net Core - SOAP - xsd.exe - cannot generate classes because no top-level elements with complex type were found

Tags: c#, soap, xsd

I try to generate classes from some xsd files

I follow this tutorial : https://justsimplycode.com/2020/02/02/soap-web-service-in-net-core-using-soapcore/

**the whole idea is to create a SOAP requests in .NET Core**

so I use the command line : **xsd.exe -c open.xsd /n:SampleSoapWebService.Models.CommonTypes**

at first it complained the schema could not be validated so I added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

but now I get a message saying it cannot generate any class

how can I validate this xsd and make xsd.Exe create my c# code ?

**open.xsd** content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://bvdep.com/webservices/">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <web:Open>
            <web:username>USERNAME</web:username>
            <web:password>PASSWORD</web:password>
        </web:Open>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

thanks for helping me on this

Comment: Tutorial uses `actionA.xsd actionB.xsd`. Did you try using both Xsd?

Comment: these files dont exist in my case, I got my own xsd, I used 4 xsd files, but I give the example with only one

Comment: For your own service can't you just add a  Service reference? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Comment: I'll use another tutorial, even their XSD cannot get validated...Also they don't look like the soap format of the files I received from the 3rd parties...where it takes a couple of lines of code in PHP, .NET complicates everything

Comment: The Envelope prefix is "soap".  So the namespace has to match the namespace of soap in the xml.  The sample is using "s" as the prefix while your code is using "soap"as the prefix.  So make sure you change all the prefixes.

Comment: You know that the example that you've given is not an xsd but an xml. I do not think that xsd.exe know's how to deal with xml files. And making a soap call isn't that hard in C#. The example that @xdtTransform provided is the simplest solution but with little effort you can do it manually as well.